# Initialize field before super constructor runs?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, initialization, constructor-chaining

In Java, is there any way to initialize a field before the super constructor runs?

Even the ugliest hacks I can come up with are rejected by the compiler:

```
class Base
{
    Base(String someParameter)
    {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    private final int a;

    Derived(String someParameter)
    {
        super(hack(someParameter, a = getValueFromDataBase()));
    }

    private static String hack(String returnValue, int ignored)
    {
        return returnValue;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "a has value " + a;
    }
}
```

Note: The issue disappeared when I switched from inheritance to delegation, but I would still like to know.

Comment: are you trying to pre-initialize field `a`?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Any initialization you do in a class (even if it is outside the constructor) is moved to every constructor after the `super` call. So, the super constructor is always run before the field initialization.

Comment: @FredOverflow since `a` is only accessible in `Derived`, why does it matter that it gets initialised *before* `super()` is called? Initialising it right after does not make a difference in the example your provide (unless you call an overriden method from the Base constructor, which begins to smell quite fishy).

Comment: Effective Java Item 17: "*Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, directly or indirectly (...) If the overriding method depends on any initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will not behave as expected.*"

Comment: can a final variable be initialized in the constructor?

Comment: @codeMan. Yeah of course. Look for Immutable classes.

Comment: @RohitJain Din't know that! Thanks.

Comment: Ugly Hack: Create the Derived class directly in java bytecode as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278865/clarifications-on-bytecode-and-objects/3280665#3280665

Comment: @assylias Actually, it does make a difference in my example, because `System.out.println(this)` internally calls `toString()`, which is overriden to print the value of `a`.

Comment: @FredOverflow Yes that was my point - it is the only situation where it makes a difference and one which you probably want to avoid.

Comment: I think this one has a nicer solution that can be used for this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303604/is-it-possible-to-do-computation-before-super-in-the-constructor, Maybe instead of a hack() function you'll need to do a Hack class, and then you can really use the solution in the link

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

According to the [language specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), instance variables aren't even initialized until a `super()` call has been made.

These are the steps performed during the constructor step of class instance creation, taken from the link:

> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter
>      variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation
>      (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using this),
>      then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation
>      recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor
>      invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes
>      abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor
>      invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If
>      this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this
>      constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a
>      superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and
>      process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using
>      these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes
>      abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same
>      reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers
>      for this class, assigning the values of instance variable
>      initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the
>      left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source
>      code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers
>      results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed
>      and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception.
>      Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution
>      completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the
>      same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

Comment: @mkilic: Pretty sure

Answer (score 16):

Super constructor will run in any case, but since we are talking about the "ugliest hacks", we can take advantage of this

```
public class Base {
    public Base() {
        init();
    }

    public Base(String s) {
    }

    public void init() {
    //this is the ugly part that will be overriden
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{

    @Override
    public void init(){
        a = getValueFromDataBase();
    }
}
```

I never suggest using these kind of hacks.

Comment: +1 - You're right. Ick. I was thinking of C++. Still -- I don't think the hack is necessary - see my answer.

Comment: This isn't really _before_ the super constructor runs, as OP asked. Probably the closest you can get though.

Comment: @Keppil I mentioned in the answer "Super constructor will run in any case", this just a hack to initialize a variable in the derived class

Answer (score 9):

I got a way to do this.

```
class Derived extends Base
{
    private final int a;

    // make this method private
    private Derived(String someParameter,
                    int tmpVar /*add an addtional parameter*/) {
        // use it as a temprorary variable
        super(hack(someParameter, tmpVar = getValueFromDataBase()));
        // assign it to field a
        a = tmpVar;
    }

    // show user a clean constructor
    Derived(String someParameter)
    {   
        this(someParameter, 0)
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, you can't initialize the instance field before calling the superclass constructor.

But there are workarounds. One is to create a factory class that gets the value and passes it to the Derived class's constructor.

```
class DerivedFactory {
    Derived makeDerived( String someParameter ) {
        int a = getValueFromDataBase();
        return new Derived( someParameter, a );
    }
}


class Derived extends Base
{
    private final int a;

    Derived(String someParameter, int a0 ) {
        super(hack(someParameter, a0));
        a = a0;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion. The only thing I would change is that I would put a static factory method inside the `Derived` class.

Answer (score 1):

It's prohibited by the [Java language specification (section 8.8.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> **The first statement** of a constructor body may be an explicit
>   invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct
>   superclass.

The constructor body should look like this:

> ConstructorBody:
>
> ```
> { ExplicitConstructorInvocationopt BlockStatementsopt }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

although it's not possible to do it directly, you can try to do it with nested object

so with your example:

```
open class Base {
    constructor() {
        Timber.e(this.toString())
    }
}

class Derived {
    val a = "new value"

    val derivedObject : Base =  object : Base() {
        override fun toString(): String {
             return "a has value " + a;
        }
    }
}
```

Happy coding - it's hack but works :) remember to define derivedObject as **LAST**  variable

Answer (score 0):

I designed a hierarchy of UI forms which ran into a similar issue. I found a similar case and some workarounds here: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue086-Initialising-Fields-Before-Superconstructor-Call.html

I changed a little the implementation of their first workaround to make it more generic (by accepting a variable number of parameters):

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    int someVariable; // not relevant for the answer
    
    public BaseClass (int someVariable, Object... arguments) {
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
        
        // Must be called before using local variables of derived class
        initializeLocalVariablesOfDerivedClass(arguments);
        
        useLocalVariablesOfDerivedClass();
    }
    
    protected abstract void initializeLocalVariablesOfDerivedClass (Object... arguments); 
    
    protected abstract void useLocalVariablesOfDerivedClass();
        
}

public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    protected String param1;
    protected Integer param2;
    
    public DerivedClass(int someVariable, Object... arguments) {
        super(someVariable, arguments);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeLocalVariablesOfDerivedClass(Object... arguments) {
        // you must know the order and type of your local fields
        param1 = (String) arguments[0];
        param2 = (Integer) arguments[1];        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void useLocalVariablesOfDerivedClass() {
        System.out.println("param1: " + param1);
        System.out.println("param2: " + param2);                
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        new DerivedClass(1, new String("cucu"), new Integer("4"));
    }
}
```