# final vairable initialization relative to super class constructor

Tags: java, initialization, final, superclass

As this ([Initialize field before super constructor runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682457/initialize-field-before-super-constructor-runs)) post states, all non static variables get initialized after the super class constructor runs, but in the following example, while debugging I see that the variable isn't initialized before the parent constructor runs, the print function prints the result "B=5" as if it was initialized.

When I use a non final variable the result is "B=0" as expected.

What's going on?

here is the code:

```
public class A {
    int a=77;
    public A(int i){
        printMe();
    }

    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("A "+a);
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    //static int a=5; //test  will print 5
    final int a=5; //test  will print 5
    //int a=5;         ////test will print 0
    public B() {
        super(0);
    }

    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("B="+a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
final int a=5;
```

is a constant variable, which is a constant expression. The compiler will replace all references to it with its value.

So

```
System.out.println("B="+a);
```

will actually compile to

```
System.out.println("B="+5); // B=5
```