# Get the file being written by FileWriter in Java

Tags: java, file

Is there a way that i can Get the file it being written in case of FileWirter. I dont have any reference to the File object with me.

```
public class JobResponseWriter extends FileWriter{
    public JobResponseWriter(Job job) throws IOException {
        super(File.createTempFile("JobResponse" + job.getId() ,"tmp"));
    }

    public void writeLn(String str) throws IOException {
        super.write(str + "\n");
    }
}
```

How can I get the File that got created in this case. I will access thefile only after the writer is closed..But i dont want to keep a separate list of all the file created. Whats the best way.

Comment: Do you have to use the super constructor to create the temp file?

Comment: I need the JobResponseWriter to behave as A FileWriter, If you have any other way..to that let me know

Comment: This is a standard problem of "Composition over inheritance". You should make a `File` member variable and "simulate" the Filewriter class instead of directly extending it

Comment: Alright...i got it...is there a way i can Find the File from FileWriter instance ??

Comment: If you could get the file, what exactly would you want to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to save a reference to the File:

```
public class JobResponseWriter extends FileWriter{
    private final File myFile;
    public JobResponseWriter(Job job) throws IOException {
        this(File.createTempFile("JobResponse" + job.getId() ,"tmp"));
    }
    public JobResponseWriter(File f) throws IOException {
        super(f);
        myFile = f;
    }
    /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah. Wasn't thinking about that way

Comment: This is what exactly i have implemented..basically the file creation logic i have taken out...

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't get the file before the super call

[Initialize field before super constructor runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682457/initialize-field-before-super-constructor-runs)

You could try something like this

```
public class JobResponseWriter {

    private final File f;
    private final fw;

    public JobResponseWriter(Job job) throws IOException {
        this.f = File.createTempFile("JobResponse" + job.getId() ,"tmp"));
        this.fw = new FileWriter(f);
    }

    public void writeLn(String str) throws IOException {
        fw.write(str + "\n");
    }

    // public void getFile() 
}
```

You may want to implement these interfaces if you want the full functionality of a filewriter-like object

`Closeable, Flushable, Appendable, AutoCloseable`

Answer (score -1):

According to the [official document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), there is no way to retrive the `File` object. And it's also not possible with `FileWriter`. However, by seeing the problm from a different perspective, you may come up like this (Assuming `Job` is your class. You can extend from `Job` if it's not):

```
public class JobResponseWriter extends FileWriter{
    File jobResponse = null;
    public FileWriter getJobResponseWriter() {
        if(jobResponse == null)
            jobResponse = File.createTempFile("JobResponse" + getId() ,"tmp"));
        return new FileWriter(jobResponse, true); //Open in append mode
    }

    public File getJobResponseFile() {
        if(jobResponse == null)
            jobResponse = File.createTempFile("JobResponse" + getId() ,"tmp"));
        return jobResponse;
    }

    //And the original methods here
}
```

Comment: Um... Wait. I think I got confused with C++. Possibily not like that, but inside the method `<init>`. I'll come back after checking it.

Comment: This is not possible solution in Java

Comment: @Ysak So I edited the code. I saw the problem from a different perspective. And it definitely should work.

Comment: @cricket_007 - it's not necessary to initialize before the super call. it's enough to initialize afterwards. see my answer